# ftp programming in F#

Tags: f#, ftp

I need to write a program in F# that should push files to an FTP server. Is there a library than I can use? I haven’t been able to find anything on the web. Can someone point me in t the right direction? If possible some sample code would be very helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`System.Net.WebRequest.Create` works well, when you give it a `ftp://` URL.

To get access to FTP-specific functionality (such as uploading files), cast your `WebRequest` object to `FtpWebRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim. whne i tried to case the WebRequest to FtpWebRequest i am getting the following error "The value or constructor 'FtpWebRequest' is not defined"

this is now i am trying to do the casting:
let reqFTP: FtpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest) (WebRequest.Create(uri))

Any thoughts?

Comment: That's C# syntax, not F#. In F# you want: `let reqFTP: FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) :?> FtpWebRequest`

Answer (score 4):

[FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) should do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `FtpWebRequest` is deprecated. FluentFTP is a great library that is being regularly updated.

```
#r "nuget: FluentFTP"

open FluentFTP

let ip = "45.33.2.79"
let username = "username"
let passwd = "s$cret"

let lpath = fsi.CommandLineArgs[1]
let rpath = fsi.CommandLineArgs[2]

let launch () =

    use con = new FtpClient(ip, username, passwd)
    con.Connect()

    let status =
        con.UploadFile(lpath, rpath, FtpRemoteExists.Overwrite, true, FtpVerify.Retry)

    match status with
    | FtpStatus.Success -> printfn "file uploaded OK"
    | FtpStatus.Failed -> printfn "failed to upload file"
    | _ -> printfn "skipped or unknown"


launch ()
```

The program uploads a local file to the FTP server.